# How to prepend a string to a forward referenced variable in the assignment?

Tags: php

I want to prepend a string ("#") to subKey1 ("TEST") in one go in the assignment, but I can't figure out the correct syntax or which functions to use:

```php
    $array = [
        "key1" => [
            "subKey1" => &$ref, // this works (without prepending)
        //  "subKey1" => "#" . &$ref, // this doesn't work :(
        ],
        "key2" => [
            "subKey2" => ($ref="TEST"),
        ],
    ];
    print $array['key1']['subKey1']; // result should be: #TEST
```

Comment: `// this doesn't work`...in what way? Is there an error?

Comment: P.s. any particular reason you're passing the ref variable by reference?

Comment: Just remove the reference operator and swap the order of the keys, so that key2 gets assigned first. If you need the keys to be a specific order at the end, you can still apply a usort inline.

Comment: @ADyson 1.) Yes, I wrote that I can't figure out the correct syntax, thus assume it's an syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "&" in test.php on line 3. (2.) Yes, because $ref is yet not defined at this point (hence: forward reference): Warning: Undefined variable $ref in test.php on line 3

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes, I need it in a particular order. usort did the job, but I had to alter a lot. Needed a sortable id key per subkey, turn arround everything, write a cmp function. The question is, if there is a way to concat right in the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this.

You can define a reference that points to a variable that doesn't exist yet, and that's ok because it's just a placeholder. At that point, it's essentially just pointing to nothing. However, as soon as you try to *use* that value, you dereference the reference, and PHP needs to know what it's pointing to. So, you can do this just fine:

```
$foo = &$bar;
$bar = 123;
var_dump($foo); // dereferencing happens here
```

This works because `$foo` is not used until *after* a value is available in `$bar`. However, if we just slightly change that code:

```
$foo = &$bar;
var_dump($foo); // dereferencing happens here
$bar = 123;
```

Then it no longer works, because `$bar` doesn't yet contain a value at the time we're trying to use it.

So, your first example works fine because you don't dereference that key (by printing it) until after the reference has been filled:

```
$array = [
    "key1" => [
        "subKey1" => &$ref,
    ],
    "key2" => [
        "subKey2" => $ref = "TEST",
    ],
];
print_r($array); // dereferencing happens here, $ref is defined already
```

Your second example can not possibly work, because now, at the time you're defining `subKey1`, the string operation requires PHP to dereference `$ref` to find out what's in it -- but there's nothing in it yet:

```
$array = [
    "key1" => [
        "subKey1" => "#" . &$ref, // dereferencing happens here, $ref is not defined yet
    ],
    "key2" => [
        "subKey2" => $ref = "TEST",
    ],
];
print_r($array);
```

I presume here that the key is being dynamically generated, and that you can't just put it in a function because it'll generate twice. If this is the case, you could use a static value to grab the key at the time you need the reference, and hold on to it until you need the key:

```
function getKey()
{
    static $key = null;
    if ($key === null) {
        $key = mystery_function_that_generates_the_key();
    }
    return $key;
}

$array = [
    "key1" => [
        "subKey1" => '#' . getKey(),
    ],
    "key2" => [
        "subKey2" => getKey(),
    ],
];
print_r($array);
```